# How to make an array of responses from fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express

I am making a music player. My songs are placed in a folder named `music`. I have a route in my backend to get the metadata of songs. I have an array which has paths for songs, and with the song path I am getting song metadata from my backend. I am using a `forEach` loop to get metadata for each song. I am getting an array, but that array is not full. Every time I try, the array has a different number of elements. I think that the array is not properly built from the responses. When I try to log this array's first element, I get `undefined`.

However if I wait a little bit, I sometimes get the first element instead. If I print it just after I am getting `undefined`.

Total number of songs:

[image: Total songs (22)]

Every time I get a different number of elements:

| 1st time | 2nd time |
| --- | --- |
| I got 10 songs metadata | I got 6 songs metadata |
| [image] | [image] |

On my backend, I have:

```js
const express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
const {
  readdir
} = fs.promises;
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const jsmediatags = require('jsmediatags');

const app = express();
const port = 5783;

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/getsongs', async(req, res) => {

  try {
    let files = [];
    const getFileList = async(dirName) => {
      const items = await readdir(dirName, {
        withFileTypes: true
      });

      for (const item of items) {

        if (item.isDirectory()) {
          files = [...files, ...(await getFileList(`${dirName}/${item.name}`)), ];
        } else {
          files.push(`${dirName}/${item.name}`);
        }
      }
      return files;
    };

    getFileList(path.join(__dirname, '../music/')).then((files) => {

      let songsPathsForMD = [];
      let songsPaths = []
      const getrelPath = async(files) => {
        await files.forEach(file => {
          const relativePath = '../music/' + file.slice(82);
          const newPath = relativePath.replace(/ +/g, '%20');
          songsPathsForMD.push(relativePath)
          songsPaths.push(newPath)
        })
        return {
          songsPathsForMD,
          songsPaths
        };
      }

      getrelPath(files).then((hello) => {
        return res.status(200).send(hello)
      })

    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: error
    })
  }

})
app.post('/getmdata', (req, res) => {
  const songPath = req.body.songpath;

  try {
    const addMdata = async(tag, songpath) => {

      const data = tag.tags.picture.data;
      let base64String = "";
      for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        base64String += String.fromCharCode(data[index])

      }

      let md = await {
        songPath: songpath.replace(/ +/g, '%20'),
        songTitle: tag.tags.title,
        songArtist: tag.tags.artist,
        songAlbum: tag.tags.album,
        coverFormat: tag.tags.picture.format,
        coverData: base64String,
        songDuration: 0

      }
      return md

    }

    jsmediatags.read(songPath, {
      onSuccess: async(tag) => {
        await addMdata(tag, songPath).then((mdata) => {
          return res.status(200).send(mdata)
        })
      },
      onError: function(error) {
        console.log(':(', error.type, error.info);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: error
    })
    // console.log('error');
  }
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The backend started at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

On my frontend, where I make the request:

```js
const getSongsPathList = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5783/getsongs')
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonData);
  return jsonData;
}

getSongsPathList().then(async(pathArray) => {
  const {
    songsPaths,
    songsPathsForMD
  } = pathArray;
  console.log(songsPathsForMD);
  let songsData = [];
  await songsPathsForMD.forEach(async path => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5783/getmdata', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        songpath: path
      })

    })
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    await songsData.push(jsonResponse);
  });
  console.log('hello');
  console.log(songsData);
  console.log(songsData[0]); // showing undefined
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(songsData[0]); //it is logging the first element
  }, 10);

}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I am expecting to get an array like this:

[image: Expected array],

Just after, I want to show the first element in my console. However, I get `undefined` unless I wait a bit.

I am not working on song duration yet, so please ignore `songDuration: 0`

Comment: Please place textual content inside the question instead of images. I assume that your linked images are of arrays in the DevTools console, but I cannot access Imgur behind my current proxy.

Comment: `await foo.forEach` does not do what you think it does.  I like [this explanation](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/37d2085425c049629b80956d3c618971)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading the contents of the array before the callback had a chance to run. `forEach` always returns undefined, and `await`ing undefined will finish immediately. Your `setTimeout` gives the response a chance to come back before trying to read it. Here is a modified portion of your code:

```js
  let songsData = await Promise.all(songsPathsForMD.map(async path => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5783/getmdata', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        songpath: path
      })
    })
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    return jsonResponse;
  }));
```

This uses `Array.map` to create an array of promises instead of `undefined`, which is then passed to `Promise.all`. That returns a promise that only resolves once all of the promises in the list are resolved, which means that all of your requests will have came back. As a bonus, it also returns the values that the promises resolved with (via `return`) in an array, making it so that you don't need to `push` to a separate array and ensuring that you get the same order each time.

You do the same thing on the server, so I fixed it (and moved the code into separate functions to *massively* decrease memory usage):

```js
async function getrelPath(files) => {
  let songsPathsForMD = [];
  let songsPaths = []
  await Promise.all(files.map(file => {
    const relativePath = '../music/' + file.slice(82);
    const newPath = relativePath.replace(/ +/g, '%20');
    songsPathsForMD.push(relativePath)
    songsPaths.push(newPath)
  }))
  return {
    songsPathsForMD,
    songsPaths
  };
}
async function getFileList(dirName) => {
  let files = []
  const items = await readdir(dirName, {
    withFileTypes: true
  });

  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.isDirectory()) {
      files.push(...(await getFileList(`${dirName}/${item.name}`)))
    } else {
      files.push(`${dirName}/${item.name}`);
    }
  }
  return files;
};
```

You should remove the original `getrelPath` and `getFileList` from your code, then paste those at the end.

Comment: Thanks from heart. It worked. 

Comment: You're welcome! It helps to understand that `async` and `await` are just syntactic sugar for using Promises directly (via `.then`).

Answer (score 0):

This will def cause you issues:

> await songsPathsForMD.forEach(async path => {

That isnt going to work the way you expect.  Please see this with some details:  https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/37d2085425c049629b80956d3c618971

Instead of awaiting each in the loop, create an array of promises, then do a

> const results = await Promise.all(yourPromises)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understood this concept. I will always use this approach.